# Problems with package.path in CoronaSDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

We want to integrate a third-party Lua module (say) `foo` into our CoronaSDK application.

Main code of this module module is in `foo/init.lua`, to be required as `require 'foo'`.

We placed this module into `corona/foo`:

```
corona/foo$ ls
  init.lua
```

In `corona/main.lua` we have:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";"
  .. package.path:gsub("?.lua", "?/init.lua")
```

`require 'foo'` works in the simulator. However, it does not work on the device:

```
Lua Runtime Error: lua_pcall failed with status: 2, error message is:
module 'foo' not found:resource (foo.lua) does not exist in
archive
  no field package.preload['foo']
  no file '/var/mobile/Applications/0B609A43-54E8-40E5-9D44-F3C93CC4031E/Appname.app/foo.lua'
  no file '/var/mobile/Applications/0B609A43-54E8-40E5-9D44-F3C93CC4031E/Appname.app/foo.lua'
  no file '/var/mobile/Applications/0B609A43-54E8-40E5-9D44-F3C93CC4031E/Appname.app/foo/init.lua'
  no file '/var/mobile/Applications/0B609A43-54E8-40E5-9D44-F3C93CC4031E/Appname.app/foo/init.lua'
  no file './foo.so'
```

Strangely enough, `require 'foo.init'` does work.

Any clues?

Comment: That's very strange behavior. If `foo.init` works, then theoretically `foo` should work as well if `?/init.lua` is in your package path, which it seems to be, indicated by the error output. How is the `foo` module setup; does it return a table or does it use module()? Is it possible that Corona is using a custom `package.loaders`? Have you tried creating a minimal test case which reproduces this issue?

Comment: It is possible that Corona uses custom `package.loaders` indeed.

Comment: How is the foo module setup; does it return a table or does it use module()? 

neither, the module simply executes some code

Is it possible that Corona is using a custom package.loaders?

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/package/loaders.html

Have you tried creating a minimal test case which reproduces this issue?

yes

Answer (score 1):

Is your filename

foo.lua or Foo.lua?

it works on simulator for both cases, but in devices, the capital matters.

I had this nightmare (I wonder why my SVN client changed the capital for one of my files... I spent over an hour to find out what went wrong because my module couldn't be found in the device suddenly)

Comment: 4 years old, and still useful…

Answer (score -1):

Try this

package.path = package.path .. ";"
  .. package.path:gsub("?.lua", "?.init.lua")

path names for lua files called in packages should be done like this:

dir.luafile.lua

rather than dir/luafile.lua

hope that helps

Comment: `package.path` should use system path separators, not `.`.